# Delete MYSQL DB Entry via PHP / HTML Button

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

**Hey.**

Iam learning PHP and MYSQL atm.

So i wrote already code which will display everything from my database nicely into HTML.
I create also a **button** which says **Delete**.

Now i want to write a Code which **actually Deletes** the specific entry (all have an ID ) but iam kinda **lost**.
i know the command is: $sql = "DELETE FROM cars WHERE car_id='$car_id'"; but how can i add this event in php to the button click.

I thought in the generating code i add the car id to the button with <button **id="'.$row["car_id".'**"> and then somehow **magically** delete the entry when i click the button but iam ***stuck & lost*** in how to call it.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "";
$dbname     = "muscle_cars";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "\n");
}

$sql = "SELECT car_id, carname, hp, img, available FROM cars";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
// fetch the next row (as long as there are any) into $row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     
    
echo '
<div class="card col-3 m-3 bg-info" >
  <img src="'.$row["img"].'" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">'.$row["carname"].'</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Horsepower : '.$row["hp"].'</p>
    <p class="card-text">Available : '.$row["available"].'</p>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-danger text-white">DELETE</a>
  </div>
</div>
';
}

// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);
// Close connection
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use form with action button name to identify what part of action to do

```php
    <?php
      
        if(isset($_POST['delete_rows'])) { //<-- see input name
            ... delete anything from database ...
        } else
        if(isset($_POST['select_rows'])) { //<-- see input name
            ... select anything from database ...
        } 
    ?> 
      
    <form method="post"> 
        <input type="submit" name="delete_rows" value="Delete"/>
        <input type="submit" name="select_rows" value="Select"/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two ways:

1:
use GET method:

```
<a href="/delete.php?id='.$row['car_id'].'" class='btn btn-outline-danger text-white'>DELETE</a>
```

In the **delete.php**:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
```

And query the delete.

2:
use ajax:

```
 <button value="'.$row['car_id'].'" class="btn btn-outline-danger text-white" onclick="Delete(this)">DELETE</button>
```

js:

```
   function Delete(elem) {
                var id= elem.value;
               
                      $.ajax({
                        url: "delete.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {id: id},
                        success: function (data) {

                            alert('Done');
                            
                        }
                    });
                

            }
```

in delete.php:

```
 $id=$_POST['id'];
```

And query the delete.

Please improve all your query.([prepare stmt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php))

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways
1- you can make a hyperlink and pass row value to it like `<a herf="page.php ? Id= $row['id']>del</>`
2- you can make a button inside form method post  and post the id and delete the record .

*Note: in php it work with name tag not the id*

I hope this answer help you